# Office interop and setup project

Tags: .net, interop, setup-project

I create XBAP application, which use Office Interop (Interop.Word.dll, Office.dll etc.).
I would like to find out if I can without violating Microsoft license agreement include this dlls to my application setup project, which I provide my customers.

PS. Sorry for my English.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The names you use do not sound familiar but resemble those auto-generated when you add a COM reference to an Office app.  Yes, no problem redistributing them, they don't contain any code.

Comment: I'm sorry for mistake. I mean references such as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word or Office.

Comment: Is not required that customers had installed Office? Don't I break law redistributing my application contains this interops?

Comment: Even if you distribute the interop DLL's, they won't do anything without the actual office apps..